# Fastlane Script - description version in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, continuous-integration, apk, fastlane

Does anyone know how can I put the text "What's new in this version?" inside Fastfile using Fastlane?

Google Play field:
[image]

Fastline script:

```
lane :googleplay do | options |
    track = options[:track]

    supply(
            track: track,
            'parameter': ?
        )

end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Fastlane Docs

Changelogs (What's new)

You can add changelog files under the changelogs/ directory for each locale. The filename should exactly match the version code of the APK that it represents. fastlane supply init will populate changelog files from existing data on Google Play if no metadata/ directory exists when it is run.

```
└── fastlane
    └── metadata
       └── android
          ├── en-US
          │   └── changelogs
          │       ├── 100000.txt
          │       └── 100100.txt
          └── fr-FR
              └── changelogs
                   └── 100100.txt
```

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply#readme